A writer tries to escape from her surreal, post apocalyptic novel
It's an Asian movie(maybe Korean). The movie was about a writer who gets involved in her own novel. She meets weird people in that surreal realm and tries to escape from it. She gets help from an old man, the scene is in a theme park, they're standing near a ferris-wheel. 
That's all I can remember... 

Sounds like the 2006 Hong Kong horror film Re-cycle. From an online recap:

Angelica Lee plays Tsui Ting-Yin, a best-selling author... she is currently writing a horror novel titled Re-cycle... Life begins to get creepy when events begin to mirror [what] she is writing – although it is not altogether clear whether her novel is coming to life or life is inspiring her novel. Eventually, Ting-Yin finds herself in a perplexing parallel world that seems to be less the novel she is writing than the discarded pages she threw away. Lost and confused, she gains assistance from an old man...

And here's a frame from the movie where they talk in front of a ferris wheel:

